# Obj-c, incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm getting this error

```
malloc: * * * error for object 0x8a591d4: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc
No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc
```

It comes from this line

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" 
       ofType:@"plist"];
NSData *plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSDictionary *loadedPlist = 
[NSPropertyListSerialization  propertyListFromData:plistData 
       mutabilityOption:0 format:NULL errorDescription:NULL]; <<< this line
```

The value of plistData is set to Summary Unavailable

I'm not sure where to start ?

**EDIT - added more code**

Comment: Post at the very least, the whole line that is causing the error. My suggestion is, all the code involved in that call, including how you set up plistData.

Comment: No idea if this will help, but try passing the argument `nil` instead of `NULL` - I can't remember if it makes a difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to add another answer: it's also possible that you have ALREADY hosed the heap, and you're failing on propertyListFromData: just because it does a lot of allocations and happens to hit the bad spot. So edit your scheme in Xcode, and make sure you have all of the Memory Management items checked (in the Diagnostics tab of the Run task).

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break? This at least gives you a backtrace and you might see something of note. If nothing else, you could try `po plistData` from the GDB console.

BTW, while it may not help, I'd think `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

How is Info.plist being stored? Is it a standard plist/xml file? Would the following solve the problem you are trying to solve, and possibly prevent this issue from happening?

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" 
       ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *loadedPlist = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Or if you want an auto-released object...

```
NSDictionary *loadedPlist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```